# CAS Server that supports Facebook/Twitter authentication via OAuth

Tags: java, php, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I'm looking for a CAS server which supports Facebook/Twitter authentication via OAuth for Single-Sign-On. I've checked JASIG-CAS server but it doesn't look support them. My java web app is based on Spring Security 3 and other external PHP apps. Does it exist a CAS server with Facebook/Twitter support? Or an extension (or sample code) for this support on JASIG?

Comment: At which point specifically do you have the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasig CAS 3.5 will hopefully provide you with oauth authentication. It is not yet available as of writing this answer. But you can check out the release candidate of version 3.5.

Have a look here:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OAuth+client+support

The source for 3.5 RC1 is available here:
https://github.com/Jasig/cas/

If your idea of integration of facebook twitter logins to cas is all about aggregation of various logins to one centralized login service, then this should be the right thing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You generally wouldn't ask Facebook/Twitter to pass authentication assertions to CAS but instead pass them directly to your application. Spring security supports OpenId and OAuth so this is relatively easy. You could then use CAS alongside Facebook and Twitter.