# CAS server for oauth authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

1. What is the main difference between Single sign on and oauth.
2. If I build CAS server for Single sign on.can I use CAS server for oauth authentication in other application(ex.Facebook).

Comment: 1) see docs [here](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/oauth). 2) see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831879/cas-server-that-supports-facebook-twitter-authentication-via-oauth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 1stquestion:

**OAuth** is an authorization protocol that allows a user to selectively decide which services can do what with a user’s data.
For instance, if you attempt to log into Spotify using Facebook, you’ll be redirected to Facebook’s website for authorization.

**Single Sign-On**, on the other hand, is a not a protocol — it’s more of a high-level concept used by a wide range of service providers (sometimes with confusing differences).
SSO is an authentication / authorization flow through which a user can log into multiple services using the same credentials.

For instance, at your company, you might want to use one set of credentials to access:

- Your internal company website.
- Your Salesforce account.
- Your Atlassian account. etc.

Instead of making each employee at your company create different accounts for each of those services they use all the time, you can instead create a single account for each employee that grants them access to all of your company services. This is **SSO**.

So, OAuth is not about Single Sign-On. It is not about you controlling what the user can access. 
It is about letting the user to control how their resources may be accessed by third-parties. Two very different use-cases.

**CAS** centralizes authentication. 
Use it if you want all your (probably internal) applications to ask users to login to a single server (all applications are configured to point to a single CAS server).